# Are non-trivial topologies in the gravitational path integral related to large gauge transformations in Yang-Mills?

Tags: gauge-theory, path-integral, quantum-gravity, topology, yang-mills

While the gravitational path integral is not a well-understood concept mathematically, a number of works (particularly in recent research connected to AdS/CFT) emphasize the importance of integrating over metrics on surfaces with nontrivial topologies as well as surfaces diffeomorphic to a flat spacetime. These metrics are obviously not continuously deformable to a flat spacetime metric.

A superficially similar concept occurs in Yang-Mills with the notion of a large gauge transformation, which relates gauge configurations that are equivalent but not homotopically equivalent. In Yang-Mills one can also introduce a "topological term" which has no effect on the equations of motion, but computes the homotopy class of the gauge configuration. There is a somewhat analogous object in gravity, the Gauss-Bonnet term, which has no effect on the EOMs and which computes the Euler characteristic of a spacetime.

My question is: is there a sense in which integrating over nontrivial topologies in a "gravitational path integral" approach to quantum gravity can be understood as including large gauge transformations in the gauge group of the theory?

Comment: i’m not sure what you have in mind here, but non-trivial topologies in the gravitational path integral are normally thought to provide physical contributions, whereas gauge transformations (whether large of continuously connected to the identity) are not, so they are certainly not the same things.